# Null Propagation operator Error BC36716 in ASP.NET 4.6 Targeted View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have an MVC solution originally compiled in VS2013 targeted for .NET 4.5. Anxiously awaiting the VS2015 null propagation operator, I opened the solution and recompiled it in VS2015. I tested the following line in a Controller and it worked fine:

```
Dim test = If(clientLocRec?.Website, clientRec.Website)
```

I was thrilled! The same line, however, in the corresponding View (in a Code block), produces an error code BC36716. I then changed the target to .NET 4.6 and still get the error, but again only in the View. My questions are the following:

1. Is this a bug or something that I am doing something wrong?
2. I assume 4.6 is required for the runtime compilation on ASP.NET if I want to use some of the VS2015 language additions like the propagation operator. Am I correct in that assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this Nuget package to your solution:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/

The nuget package should modify your web.config, but check that the following configuration is in your web.config file (and if it isn't add it in):

```xml
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

This goes right inside the `<configuration />` element.

This will swap out the codedom generators with Roslyn powered ones. After that, this will work in your razor views.

I believe MVC 5.2.3 or newer is required for this to work correctly.

Comment: Incredibly quick reply! ++ Thanks! Follow-up on question #2 - is my assumption correct that I need .NET 4.6 targeted to use some of the new language features of VS2015?

Comment: @HumbleBeginnings No, most (if not all) of the C# 6 / VB.NET 14 features work fine in the .NET Framework 4.5.x, including the null-safety operator. In fact, the null safety operator will work fine in .NET 2.0.

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones it seems to be working under 4.52. Also FYI the nuget pkg dropped right and and the error went away - didn't even have to restart! :-) thx again.