# is there a null conditional operator in Vbnet?

Tags: c#, vb.net

cIn C# there is a null conditional operator `?.` (sometimes called the Elvis operator) like so:

```
var name = project?.customer?.name;
```

which doesn't fail but instead return `null` if `project` or `customer` is null.

Is there an equivalent in VB.NET?

Note that I am not looking for [`If(b, x, y)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net) but the very [`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) replacement.

Comment: I am surprised **I** haven't found any answer when searching and nothing in Stack overflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730494/null-propagation-operator-error-bc36716-in-asp-net-4-6-targeted-view

Comment: Please type in your C# sample again without typos.  It's hard to tell exactly what your question is (I count 2 typos - in addition to the obscure 'Elvis' naming).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas In fairness, "Elvis operator" was a commonly used name when the operator didn't have an official name yet.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Yes, in other languages, "Elvis operator" refers to `?:`, but C# never had `?:`. When C# gained `?.`, the same name was used unofficially.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks for clearing that up - so yes the original question is about the 'Elvis operator' (but should be rewritten to actually be coherent C#).

Comment: Thanks - now I have something (Elvis operator) that I can bring up at parties (maybe not).

Comment: It seems that I was wrong in multiple ways. First the code typo which was a **big** error on my side but was thankfully fixed by @zdeněk-jelínek. Then there was my overuse of the term Elvis operator. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) which states that C# does not really have an Elvis operator. A bit funny though that my typo looked like [the real Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator). Third, and hopefully last, there was my brain that seemed to be unlucky when thinking and didn't recognise the operator was the same in C# and Vbnet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

VB also has the null conditional operator (never heard the term 'Elvis' operator):

```
Dim name = customer?.name
```

Notes:

1. Inferred typing in VB requires `Option Infer On`
2. I'm pretty sure that your original C# code sample should have been:

   ```cs
   var name = customer?.name;
   ```

Comment: 1. I believe `Option Infer On` is set as default.  
2. A typo of mine. Thank you for correcting.  

The syntax is the same in C# and Vbnet. Schtoopid of me.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yeah - saw that when I looked it up, but had never heard anyone call it that before today.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas The term "Elvis operator" was actually used by C# language design team members (I believe it was Mads Torgersen) in the C#6 spotlight video for the _null-propagating operator_ feature. While the wikipedia page specifically mentions the Elvis operator as being ternary conditional, it also has a link to the safe navigation operator in the See Also part. So it's not that it's entirely wrong.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know this worked for vb.net too.